# Probability of intersection of two sets of numbers

Tags: probability

Safe code consists of 4 randomly selected digits. What is the probability that the safe code contains at least 1 of the 3 pre-given digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about *digits*, so there are 10 choices.

Probability = 1 - (Probability that none of the numbers are one of the "pre-given numbers")
There are 10 - 3 = 7 "non-pre-given" numbers, and four spaces to be filled.

Hence, probability = $$1 - \bigg({\frac{7}{10}}\bigg)^4$$
$$\implies 1 - 0.2401 = 0.7599 = 75.99\%$$

Comment: Thank you! Which topic I may have to learn to understand and successfully do this type of problems? Basic combinatorics?

Comment: @eltanin Basic combinatorics and probability calculus I'd say.